# Duplicate class androidx. found in modules classes.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, buildbox

I got this errors when I try to generate signed apk for my project

> Duplicate class androidx.collection.LongSparseArray found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.collection.LruCache found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$ArrayIterator found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$EntrySet found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$KeySet found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$MapIterator found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$ValuesCollection found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.collection.SimpleArrayMap found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.collection.SparseArrayCompat found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NavUtils found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$BigPictureStyle found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$BigTextStyle found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Builder found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$InboxStyle found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Style found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompatJellybean found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat$IntentBuilder found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat$IntentReader found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.content.ContextCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.content.FileProvider found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.content.FileProvider$PathStrategy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.content.IntentCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.content.pm.ActivityInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.internal.view.SupportMenu found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.internal.view.SupportMenuItem found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.internal.view.SupportSubMenu found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.net.TrafficStatsCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.os.EnvironmentCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.text.TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat$AnyStrong found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.text.TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat$FirstStrong found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.text.TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat$TextDirectionAlgorithm found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.text.TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat$TextDirectionHeuristicImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.text.TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat$TextDirectionHeuristicInternal found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.AutoScrollHelper$ScrollAnimationRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.EdgeEffectCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.ListPopupWindowCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.ListViewAutoScrollHelper found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.PopupMenuCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.ScrollerCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter$ChangeObserver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter$MyDataSetObserver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter$CursorFilterClient found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$CursorToStringConverter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$ViewBinder found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.customview.widget.ExploreByTouchHelper found in modules classes.jar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.customview.widget.ExploreByTouchHelper$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.customview.widget.ViewDragHelper found in modules classes.jar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.customview.widget.ViewDragHelper$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.customview.widget.ViewDragHelper$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.customview.widget.ViewDragHelper$Callback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout found in modules classes.jar (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$AccessibilityDelegate found in modules classes.jar (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams found in modules classes.jar (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$SavedState found in modules classes.jar (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$SavedState$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$BackStackEntry found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$OnBackStackChangedListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$3 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$4 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTabHost found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTabHost$DummyTabFactory found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTabHost$SavedState found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTabHost$SavedState$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTabHost$TabInfo found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.SuperNotCalledException found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.legacy.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle found in modules classes.jar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.legacy.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate found in modules classes.jar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.legacy.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider found in modules classes.jar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.legacy.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.legacy.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$ForceLoadContentObserver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$OnLoadCompleteListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$3 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$4 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$AsyncTaskResult found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$Status found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$WorkerRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager found in modules classes.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$BroadcastRecord found in modules classes.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$ReceiverRecord found in modules classes.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.print.PrintHelper found in modules classes.jar (androidx.print:print:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.print.PrintHelper$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.print:print:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout found in modules classes.jar (androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$AccessibilityDelegate found in modules classes.jar (androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$DisableLayerRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$DragHelperCallback found in modules classes.jar (androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$LayoutParams found in modules classes.jar (androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$PanelSlideListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$SavedState found in modules classes.jar (androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$SavedState$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$SimplePanelSlideListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$ViewPositionComparator found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-19.0.1.jar (support-v4-19.0.1.jar)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following lines to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

In case you can't find `gradle.properties` file, simply create it in the root directory of your project and add the lines above to it.

Comment: thanks i resolved the problem i was adding a jar file that was not important so i get the class duplication